# index.js file is not generated when eject my expo react-native app

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to `React Native` and `expo`. I created a new project with that command
`expo init my-app` then I opened my project with VSCode and run that command 
`expo eject` to eject to regular `React Native` app, after ejecting process is completed, I found that my project folder does not contain the `index.js` file, while the tutorial that I was following did the same steps I did before and the instructor got that `index.js` file?

What's wrong in my steps? Anyone can clear the whole idea?

Comment: Same error after ejecting from Expo. :(

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this happened with me too.

`expo eject` is not creating index.js

So, create index.js manually and add the following code to the file. It should work perfectly.

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import App from './App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('your_app_name_here', () => App);
```